# Play Framework: Form withGlobalError

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am experiencing a difficulty with the Form helper. I want to add an error to the form before passing it to the view but I get the following error:

```
value withGlobalError is not a member of play.api.data.Form[(String, String)]
```

The code I have is as follows:

```
def loginForm = Form(
            tuple (
              "email" -> nonEmptyText,
              "password" -> nonEmptyText
            )
    )   


def asignIn = Action {
      implicit request => 
        loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold (
              formWithErrors => Ok(views.html.login(formWithErrors.withGlobalError("Invalid username or password")),
              user => authenticationStep(user)(request)
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The verification of the email and password should be done in the form like follow:

```
val loginForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "email" -> nonEmptyText,
    "password" -> text
  ) verifying("Invalid user name or password", fields => fields match { 
      case (email, pwd) => User.authenticate(email,pwd).isDefined 
  })
)
```

Comment: the reason why I am not doing it like that is because I can't return the `id` from the object that `authenticate` returns.

Comment: Well if you want the `id` you can get it in the `asignIn` function using the values you get from the `loginForm`.

Comment: so `user` in `asignIn` contains my object? From what I tested it contains the tuple (email, password). The way you are suggesting me to do it needs to make the same request twice.

Comment: Yes it only contains the tuple `(email,password)` and as you said make another request that use the email to get your object.

Comment: isn't that wasting a request? If I could use `withGlobalError` I could do that request only once. But I'm not sure about the error listed above.